# Entity Framework and ADO.NET with Unit of Work pattern

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions, domain-events

We have a system built using Entity Framework 5 for creating, editing and deleting data but the problem we have is that sometimes EF is too slow or it simply isn't possible to use entity framework (Views which build data for tables based on users participating in certain groups in database, etc) and we are having to use a stored procedure to update the data.

However we have gotten ourselves into a problem where we are having to save the changes to EF in order to have the data in the database and then call the stored procedures, we can't use ITransactionScope as it always elevates to a distributed transaction and/or locks the table(s) for selects during the transaction.

We are also trying to introduce a DomainEvents pattern which will queue events and raise them after the save changes so we have the data we need in the DB but then we may end up with the first part succeeding and the second part failing.

Are there any good ways to handle this or do we need to move away from EF entirely for this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar scenario . Later I break the process into small ones and use EF only, and make each small process short. Even overall time is longer, but system is easier to maintain and scale.  Also I minimized joins, only update entity itself, disable EF'S AutoDetectChangesEnabled and ValidateOnSaveEnabled.
Sometimes if you look your problem in different ways, you may have better solution. 
Good luck!